# The best solution for distribution website?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Ok, I have a question from a **"client"** perspective. Let's say we are talking about website designed for distribution: products + their logistics info.

Definitely less than a 2k rows, rarely changed but often accessed. Typical row with several columns will have to consist of a picture so it might make it a bit "heavy". I was proposed a websited in Django Framework coded in Python with Postgresql database.

Is it efficient? Cost-efficient, for such a small purpose is it really needed? and is there a cheaper and also reliable solution?

From what I know the porposed solution is efficient for a programmer - loads of features, flexibility, distinction between layers of code-content-graphics. It gives a chance to build rly complicated websites and databases - thus the cost of service is bigger.

What i need to know is whether the porposed solution is suitable for such a small project and could not be easily replaced by less complicated languages/frameworks/dmbses like PHP with MySQL etc.

Please help :]

and sry for not editing the q in the first place

Comment: "Efficient"?  What does that mean?  Please define your "efficiency" goal.  The technology works.  And is used heavily around the world.  What do you want to know?

Comment: Sounds efficient in man hours.

Comment: Cost-efficient ;) for such a small purpose is it rly needed? and is there a cheaper and also reliable solution?

Comment: @Barth: since all the components are free, what does "cost efficient" mean?  Nothing could be cheaper.  Please update the question to specify precisely what you need to know.

Comment: Ok, as I said at the beginning im writing this from a Client side not as a programmer. And a client that is being horribly charged I might add so im looking for a cheaper solution and asking wheter the one proposed by a designer is viable in that case

Comment: @Barth: essentially you are paying for the web developer/company who know these skills. Obviously there are many ways to skin the cat. If you feel they are expensive, you could ask for a quote from some other web dev/company. Also, a better way to judge the dev/company is to see some of the websites which they have built and get some customer feedback from their prior customers. If it does not matter where the developer sits(i.e, you dont need regular interaction,you dont care as long as he can complete the task in time etc), you can try offshoring it as well

Comment: What does "rly" mean?  Please spell words in English.

Comment: What does "sry" and "q" mean, also?  Please spell words in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What i need to know is whether the porposed solution is suitable for such a small project and could not be easily replaced by less complicated languages/frameworks/dmbses like PHP with MySQL etc.
"

Yes.  It's suitable.

No.  Nothing is "less complicated" than Django.    PHP language may appear less complicated than Python, but you'll do more work to create the site.

With Django, you define the model, define the non-administrative views and you're done.  For simple sites this can take as little as 20 minutes.  The built-in admin is more valuable than you can imagine.

MySQL is not "less complicated" that PostgresSQL -- they're the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I would not comment about Django & Python. But a more simpler way to store images would be to store just the "path" (location in the directory) in the tables, and load the path in your application/framework.

Comment: This is how django deals with uploaded files already. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Comment: Ok, the idea is that the customer enters the site chooses the products he's interested in and site generates a report - pdf or excel with choosen positions (info + pics)

Answer (score 0):

**Website** For small webservices you can use micro-frameworks like http://www.sinatrarb.com/ (which is written in ruby); you write simple and useful apps in a few dozens or hundreds of lines. Plug your database in via some object-relational mapper and you should have a working prototype within a few hours/days.

**PDF** For PDF generation, there is some great ruby library by Gregory Brown called [prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) ...

*Addendum* A python/[django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) solution isn't complicated/un-effective either ...